# python script in plone

Tags: python, plone, gdata

I am using Plone and I have one problem: I installed gdata library in my python (gdata2.6: setup.py install) I put gdata in the egg buildout.I wrote one script python to take a document and if I test it with pythonwin it works but if i put it in plone I am not able to run it.Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 3):

You've to write a browser view or an external method to use it:

http://plone.org/documentation/kb/five-zope3-walkthrough/browser-view-1

http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/views/browserviews.html

http://plone.org/documentation/kb/create-and-use-an-external-method

Comment: Thanks...I tried the 3th link but in my plone I have not a Zope folder but only bin,part,download, python...Do you Jnow where I have to put the Extension folder??

Comment: I resolved the Extension folder (I put it in instance folder and it works) but when I tried to test my script I don't see nothing. my script example is justo to print hello...

Comment: you can return "Hello!" from an external method (print maybe goes to the instance log, I don't know). When you do changes, you've to refresh the module from the external script object.